# How do I redefine a class's function outside of the class

Tags: c++, class, vector, std, void

```
class Function
{
public:
    std::string Name;
    void call(std::string x);

    Function(std::string Nam)
    {
        Name = Nam;
    }
};

std::vector<Function> funcs;

void Load_FuncLib()
{
    Function print("print");
    Function add("add");

    print.call(std::string x)
    {
        std::cout<< x <<"\n";
    }
    add.call(std::string x)
    {
        std::cout<< std::stoi(x) + std::stoi(x) << "\n";
    }

    funcs.push_back(print);
    funcs.push_back(add);

    funcs.at(0).call("Hello world");
}
```

I want it to run the function `print.call("Hello world");` but it will not work as I don't know how to set a function, which is already declared, nor do I know how to call it using a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely want to achieve something like this?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void (const std::string&)>> funcs;

    funcs["print"] = [](const std::string& str) {
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    };

    funcs["add"] = [](const std::string& str) {
        int i = std::stoi(str);
        std::cout << i + i << '\n';
    };

    funcs["print"]("Hello, World!");
    funcs["add"]("12");
}
```

https://ideone.com/Ke4aEK

At any time you can reset a certain value of the hash map with another function.
Also, depending on your needs, you may use std::function or just plain function pointers.